# angular2 Inject(Http) out of constructor

Tags: angular, inject

See the code below

```
import { Http,HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable,Inject } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
export class FINAL
{
    static configs:{};
    @Inject(Http) http:Http;
    constructor()
    {
        if(FINAL.configs === undefined)
        {
            console.log('get configs ...');
            this.http.get('../config.json').toPromise().then(response => {
                FINAL.configs = response;
                return true;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

The `this.http` is undefinded, why? And if I use `constructor( @Inject(Http) http:Http;)`: How can I get the `FINAL` class's instance by explicit like `new xx()`?

Comment: The whole point of dependency injection is that you're not supposed to use new (except in tests, with mock dependencies) to get an instance of your class. You're supposed to inject it, and let angular create it for you. Annotate the class with `@Injectable()`, add it to the providers of your module, and inject it where you need it.

Comment: The code in your question is not supposed to work. Angular injects only constructor parameters. Just a hint. In `constructor( @Inject(Http) http:Http;)` `@Inject(Http)` is redundant because it's the same type as the constructor parameter type anyway.

Comment: "How can I get the FINAL class's instance by explicit like new xx()?" where do you want to get it? I

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks so much, you resolved my puzzled about `@Inject`.